# TypeError: document.template is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

when user enter the value in textarea i want to claculate the character and show it in the textbox but i am getting an error : `TypeError: document.template is undefined`

my code:

```
<script>

    function updateCharsLeft() 
{
var counter, smsAmount; //, charLeft;

 nValue = document.template.value.charCodeAt(o);


 counter = document.template.value.length;

 if(nValue<128){

 if(counter == 0) { 
  smsAmount = 0;
 }
 else if(counter > 160) { 
  smsAmount = 1 + Math.ceil((counter -160)/152);
 }
 else { 
  smsAmount = 1; 
 }
 }else

 {
  if(counter == 0) { 
  smsAmount = 0;
 }
 else if(counter > 70) { 
  smsAmount = 1 + Math.ceil((counter -70)/63);
 }
 else { 
  smsAmount = 1; 
 }

 }

 document.intCharLeft.value = counter;
 document.SMSchain.value = smsAmount;

 if(counter < 121){
  //document.smsmobile.intCharLeft.style.color='#000000';
  //document.smsmobile.intCharLeft.style.backgroundColor='#00FF00';
 }
 else if (counter >= 121 && counter <= 160) {
  //document.smsmobile.intCharLeft.style.color='#000000';
  //document.smsmobile.intCharLeft.style.backgroundColor='#00FF00';
 }

 if(counter > 160){
  //document.smsmobile.intCharLeft.style.color='#000000';
  //document.smsmobile.intCharLeft.style.backgroundColor='#FFFF44';
 }
 //if(counter > 885)
 //{
  //{ document.smsForm.txtMsg.value = document.smsForm.txtMsg.value.substring(0, 885);}
}

    </script>
```

Html:

```
<div class="controls">
                                                <textarea onKeyUp="updateCharsLeft()" name="template" id="template" rows="5" class="input-block-level"> </textarea>

                                                <button type="submit" class="addtemplate">Save Template</button>

                                            </div>


<div class="control-group">
                                        <label for="textfield" class="control-label">No. of characters</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" style="margin:0px;width:91px" name="intCharLeft" id="intCharLeft" placeholder="Text input" class="input-xlarge">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="control-group" style="margin:0px">
                                        <label for="textfield" class="control-label">No. of messages</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" style="margin:0px;width:91px" name="SMSchain" id="SMSchain" placeholder="Text input" class="input-xlarge">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

can anyone guide me how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getElementById` instead of `document.ElementName`:

```
var template = document.getElementById('template');
```

Answer (score 0):

The automatic variables created by browsers based on element `id`s are properties of `window` (and therefore are global variables), not `document`, so you'd use just `template` (or `window.template` if you wanted to be slightly redundant but perhaps a bit clearer) not `document.template`.

But relying on those variables is not best practice, because they can be shadowed by other things that are also dumped on `window`. Instead, use `document.getElementById("template")`, which looks only at `id` values (on un-broken browsers; IE6/7 [are broken](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply i tried like this  

'nValue = document.getElementById('template').value.charCodeAt(o);' it showing an error ReferenceError: o is not defined

Comment: @Xavi: Well, what's `o`? You've used it like it's a variable, but it's not defined anywhere in your code. Perhaps you meant `0`, the digit? (That would give you the character code of the first character in the value.) In any case, that's a separate issue from the `document.template` problem.